# Is synchronous communication possible using NSURLSession

Tags: ios8, nsurlsession

I am upgrading my iOS app to iOS8 and I want to make use of NSURLSession, but my project requirement is making synchronous calls to the server. It's done simply using NSURLConnection synchronous methods. But I can't find any source about making synchronous calls using NSURLSession. In fact, I read some blogs suggesting to stick to NSURLConnection. Any ideas about synchronous communication using NSURLSession?

Comment: Why do you want to use NSURLSession at all?

Comment: There is a case where my app sends request to server in foreground and went background. In this case i wont receive response from server but its captured at server end. When i sent the same request next time its creating duplicate results. i need to avoid this case. I have tried backgroundexpirationhandler to increase time in background, but now its limited to 3 min. Planning to make use of NSURLSession  and backgroundconfiguration so that I can make request in background without interruption

Comment: Then it's better to create a GUID for your request, and send that to the server. If the app needs to resend the request for some reason, the server can detect that the GUID is duplicate and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous use of NSURLConnection is legal, but only on a background thread. This feature was misused, however, and was never really necessary; Apple is right to abolish it. You should not "stick to NSURLConnection"; it will be deprecated and withdrawn. Instead, you should rethink your approach here.